# How to create Tag based search in Redis cache using node JS?

Tags: node.js, caching, redis, nodes, node-redis

I am look for tag based search functionality in Redis cache.

Basically in relational database MYSQL or ORACLE we using LIKE operate to search the records/documents etc.
 But in Redis how do we achieve this approach?

This kind of future is available in Redis?.

Any links/examples.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to perform tag-based search in Redis is with Sets - for each of the tags, maintain a corresponding key that stores the document/record ids that are associated with it. For example, assuming that `doc1` has `tag1`, `doc2` has `tag2` and `doc3` has both `tag1` and `tag2`, you'd end up with something like:

```
SADD tag1 doc1 doc3
SADD tag2 doc2 doc3
```

Search by tag is now possible with the [`SMEMBERS`](http://redis.io/commands/smembers) (or [`SSCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/sscan)) and you can also perform more complex searches using multiple tags with Set operations (i.e. [`SUNION`](http://redis.io/commands/sunion), [`SDIFF`](http://redis.io/commands/sdiff) and [`SINTER`](http://redis.io/commands/sinter)).

Comment: Thanks Haber, Is it possible with out key(tag search)?, I mean user while search based on tags He don't no the Key. If possible any example on this. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question - the tag is the key's name in my example

Comment: Yes,  your right, In your example tag1 and tag2 is keys right?. my question is without key search is possible or not in redis?.

Answer (score 0):

Currently You can use Redis Schemas with Tags Fields
https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/advanced-concepts/tags/
And for Node there is Redis OM. So you can create the schemas with it
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-om
And for Querying Searching and Indexing there are courses on Redis University
https://university.redis.com/courses/ru203/
https://university.redis.com/courses/ru204/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35491773)